# I would to update a field in my table from mysql db - but the problem statement is as follows in the body

Tags: mysql, database

The following it the data that explains has both my problem and desired output. Please look below for more details

```
+------------+-----+--------------+-------------------+
|    Date    | ID  | Payment Done | The Problem Field |
+------------+-----+--------------+-------------------+
| 2020-02-15 | 111 |            1 |                 0 |
| 2020-03-15 | 111 |            0 |                 0 |
| 2020-04-15 | 111 |            0 |                -1 |
| 2020-03-15 | 222 |            0 |                 0 |
| 2020-03-31 | 222 |            0 |                -1 |
| 2020-04-14 | 222 |            1 |                 0 |
| 2020-02-29 | 333 |            0 |                 0 |
| 2020-03-15 | 333 |            0 |                -1 |
| 2020-03-35 | 333 |            1 |                 0 |
| 2020-04-14 | 333 |            0 |                 0 |
+------------+-----+--------------+-------------------+
```

[image]

The picture contains data to explain the problem I'm stuck with. For a given ID, if the payment is not done in a date D1 and payment is also not done in the previous date D2 (D2

So, wherever the problem field is -1, it means that during that date and also during the previous date(the difference between dates is not same always), the payment was not done by that specific ID.

I tried to to do this using a query and spent more than half a day. Then I used Python script to do this - but my ego is not satisfied yet. I would like to do this using a query - if at all possible.

MY IDEA:

```
My approach to solving was to write a query that says the following:
Take a date D1 for an ID. 
Get the Max(date) for the same ID when the date is less than D1 - meaning I'll get the immediate lesser record's date. 
Then check if "payment done" is 0 in both the rows and if yes, then update the D1 row's problem field to -1.
```

By the way, I'm not much experienced with MySQL and please forgive me for being a naive learner. The MySQL Server version I'm using is 5.6.41

I would like you to see the query(error somewhere - innermost query is unable to access the outer table's variable) that I tried to write to say that I mentioned above:

```
update my_table a set the_problem_field = -1 where 0 = (select payment_done from (select payment_done from  my_table where id = a.id and date =(select max(date) from  my_table  where id = a.id and date<a.date))T) and a.payment_done = 0;
```

The same Neatly Formatted:

```
UPDATE my_table a 
SET    the_problem_field = -1 
WHERE  0 = (SELECT payment_done 
            FROM   (SELECT payment_done 
                    FROM   my_table 
                    WHERE  id = a.id 
                           AND date = (SELECT Max(date) 
                                       FROM   my_table 
                                       WHERE  id = a.id 
                                              AND date < a.date))T) 
       AND a.payment_done = 0;
```

I would like someone to help me with this....please! Any help is very much appreciated. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Please add data as text not as picture

Comment: update my_table a set the_problem_field = -1 where 0 = (select payment_done from (select payment_done from  my_table where id = a.id and date =(select max(date) from  my_table  whereid = a.id and date<a.date))T) and a.payment_done = 0;

I've tried something like this - also, edited the same in my question. This query just represents a vague idea and it's not a working query

Comment: see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query  and add sdata as etxt and the wanted result from that data

Comment: Thanks...That link was very helpful especially to create the table. @nbk

Comment: and last which mysql version are you using, with myslq 5.x you need much more code than the window functions in 8.x but such complex alghporithm are better made in stored procedures or pythin

Comment: The MySQL Server version I'm using is 5.6.41

Answer (score 0):

There was no need for a stored procedure.
The crucial part is the inner join which produces the wanted result.

You can realizes that by "remembering" the last ID and Payment Done

Column names should not have spaces in them or else you have always to remember tol encapsulate them always

```
UPDATE Paymnettable pt
        INNER JOIN
    (SELECT 
        `Date`,
            IF(@id = ID, IF(`Payment Done` = 1, 0, IF(@Payment_Done = 0, - 1, 0)), 0) `The Problem Field`,
            @id:=ID ID,
            @Payment_Done:=`Payment Done` 'Payment Done'
    FROM
        (SELECT 
        *
    FROM
        Paymnettable
    ORDER BY `ID` , `Date`) t1
      , (SELECT @Payment_Done:=0) t2
      , (SELECT @ID:=0) t3) pt1 
    ON pt.`Date` = pt1.`Date`
        AND pt.ID = pt1.ID 
SET 
    pt.`The Problem Field` = pt1.`The Problem Field`
```

**Schema (MySQL v5.6)**

```
CREATE TABLE Paymnettable (
  `Date` DATE,
  `ID` INTEGER,
  `Payment Done` INTEGER,
  `The Problem Field` INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO Paymnettable
  (`Date`, `ID`, `Payment Done`, `The Problem Field`)
VALUES
  ('2020-02-15', '111', '1', '0'),
  ('2020-03-15', '111', '0', '0'),
  ('2020-04-15', '111', '0', '0'),
  ('2020-03-15', '222', '0', '0'),
  ('2020-03-31', '222', '0', '0'),
  ('2020-04-14', '222', '1', '0'),
  ('2020-02-29', '333', '0', '0'),
  ('2020-03-15', '333', '0', '0'),
  ('2020-03-31', '333', '1', '0'),
  ('2020-04-14', '333', '0', '0');

 UPDATE Paymnettable pt
        INNER JOIN
    (SELECT 
        `Date`,
            IF(@id = ID, IF(`Payment Done` = 1, 0, IF(@Payment_Done = 0, - 1, 0)), 0) `The Problem Field`,
            @id:=ID ID,
            @Payment_Done:=`Payment Done` 'Payment Done'
    FROM
        (SELECT 
        *
    FROM
        Paymnettable
    ORDER BY `ID` , `Date`) t1, (SELECT @Payment_Done:=0) t2, (SELECT @ID:=0) t3) pt1 ON pt.`Date` = pt1.`Date`
        AND pt.ID = pt1.ID 
SET 
    pt.`The Problem Field` = pt1.`The Problem Field`
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT 
        *
    FROM
        Paymnettable;

| Date       | ID  | Payment Done | The Problem Field |
| ---------- | --- | ------------ | ----------------- |
| 2020-02-15 | 111 | 1            | 0                 |
| 2020-03-15 | 111 | 0            | 0                 |
| 2020-04-15 | 111 | 0            | -1                |
| 2020-03-15 | 222 | 0            | 0                 |
| 2020-03-31 | 222 | 0            | -1                |
| 2020-04-14 | 222 | 1            | 0                 |
| 2020-02-29 | 333 | 0            | 0                 |
| 2020-03-15 | 333 | 0            | -1                |
| 2020-03-31 | 333 | 1            | 0                 |
| 2020-04-14 | 333 | 0            | 0                 |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ihwaUZpdhBvd4vhTqQAVsG/0)